# Polynomials: Quotient and Remainder

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How can we find the quotient and remainder when:

$$f(x)= x^5-x^4-4x^3+2x+3$$

is divided by $$g(x)=x-2?$$

Could someone please show how to step-by-step using synthetic division?

Comment: what did you attempt? Show us the work you have done.

Comment: You can use [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), the [Euclidean division algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division_of_polynomials), or [synthetic division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A practical method is as follow:**

$$\begin{align}\\
x^5-x^4-4x^3+2x+3&&&&& x-2\\
   x^4-4x^3+2x+3         &&&&&x^4\\
     -2x^3+2x+3          &&&&& x^3\\
    -4x^2+2x+3      &&&&&-2x^2\\
             -6x+3       &&&&&-4x\\
                  -9       &&&&&-6
\end{align}$$
so the quotient is $x^4+x^3-2x^2-4x-6$ and the remainder is $-9$.

**and to explain the procedure of calculus:** we divide the leading term $x^5$ of the dividend by the leading term $x$ of the divisor we find $x^4$ and then we calculate:
$$x^5-x^4-4x^3+2x+3-x^4(x-2)=x^4-4x^3+2x+3=R(x)$$

and repeat the same calculus using $R(x)$ as your new dividend until we find the remainder $R(x)$ with degree less than the degree of the divisor $x-2$.

Answer (score 0):

I still want you to attempt the question since it is really a matter of applying the synthetic division. Where do you fail to understand it? See the example below
where $f(x)=x^{5}-2x^{3}-3x^{2}$ and $g(x)=x-1$. Follow the steps

(1) If it is not clear, ask where it is unclear

(2) If it is clear, apply it to your question and we can confirm your answers

cheeers, abiyo
[image]